# (Beginner) How to get conditional statement to work in WordPress widget?

Tags: php, if-statement, wordpress

I am working on a WordPress widget and for some reason I can't get an if statement to work. I am trying to check to see if a variable is empty and if the variable is not empty than I want to display an image. If the variable is empty I do not want to show the image. Here is the statement:

```
    if (empty($facebook)) {
        echo '';

    } else { 
        echo '<a href="'.$facebook.'"><img src="'.get_option('siteurl').'/wp-content/themes/SimplePhoto/widgets/facebook.png" /></a>';

    }
```

Right now, when I run the widget, the Facebook icon shows up no matter what.

EDIT: Here is the code that builds the widget form and displays it on the front-end:

```
    function form($instance) {
    $defaults = array( 'title' => 'My Info', 'Facebook' => '', 'Twitter' => '' ); 
    $instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, $defaults );
    $title = $instance['title'];
    $facebook = $instance['facebook'];
    $twitter = $instance['twitter'];
    ?>
        <p>Title: <input class="widefat" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>"  type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>" /></p>
        <p>Facebook: <input class="widefat" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'facebook' ); ?>"  type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $facebook ); ?>" /></p>
        <p>Twitter: <textarea class="widefat" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'twitter' ); ?>" / ><?php echo esc_attr( $twitter ); ?></textarea></p>
    <?php
}

//save the widget settings
function update($new_instance, $old_instance) {
    $instance = $old_instance;
    $instance['title'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['title'] );
    $instance['facebook'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['facebook'] );
    $instance['twitter'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['twitter'] );

    return $instance;
}

//display the widget
function widget($args, $instance) {
    extract($args);

    echo $before_widget;
    $title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] );
    $facebook = empty( $instance['facebook'] ) ? '&nbsp;' : $instance['facebook'];
    $twitter = empty( $instance['twitter'] ) ? '&nbsp;' : $instance['twitter']; 

    if ( !empty( $title ) ) { echo $before_title . $title . $after_title; };


    if (empty($facebook)) {
        echo '';

    } else { 
        echo '<a href="'.$facebook.'"><img src="'.get_option('siteurl').'/wp-content/themes/SimplePhoto/widgets/facebook.png" /></a>';

    }

    echo $after_widget;
}
```

}

Comment: try `echo $facebook;` before this if and see what it gets. Put also the code where you initialize $facebook

Comment: When I add echo $facebook it shows the variable content, so it shows what is inputed into the text box. When clear the text box and save the widget than echo $facebook rightly shows nothing. I'll go ahead and add the code that builds the widget form and displays it.

Comment: actualyy it is not working because in here `$facebook = empty( $instance['facebook'] ) ? '&nbsp;' : $instance['facebook'];` you either put the value of $facebook or a space. That is why echoing did not show you anything and keeps showing the icon because you have a space character in this variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do this

```
$facebook = empty( $instance['facebook'] ) ? '' : $instance['facebook'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your variable is actually empty? try replacing with something you know is true (or false) to check your syntax